# Init Containers bypassing the command

Tags: kubernetes

I am following documentation example at https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/#init-containers-in-use

I created following pod:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: myapp-pod
  labels:
    app: myapp
spec:
  initContainers:
    - name: init-myservice
      image: busybox
      command:
        [
          "sh",
          "-c",
          "until nslookup myservice; do echo waiting for myservice; sleep 2; done;",
        ]
    - name: init-mydb
      image: busybox
      command:
        [
          "sh",
          "-c",
          "until nslookup mydb; do echo waiting for mydb; sleep 2; done;",
        ]
  containers:
    - name: myapp-container
      image: busybox
      command: ["sh", "-c", "echo The app is running! && sleep 3600"]
```

but I did not create the services yet (`myservice, mydb`).

My expectation is for deployment to **hold until I create services**, but it just continues with deployment and creates the pod called "`myapp-pod`".

Am I missing something on this run?
Why it does not hold until I create the services?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because you are using `ash` inside busybox and it has different behavior (not same as bash). So your script actually ends there.

You can try it inside busybox yourself:

```
kubectl run -i --tty busybox --image=busybox --restart=Never -- sh
```

And then use your command:

```
until nslookup myservice; do echo waiting for myservice; sleep 2; done;
```

To fix this issue you can try something different, for example **alpine**.

```
kubectl run -i --tty alpine --image=alpine --restart=Never -- sh
```

Comment: yes, that was exactly the reason. When I switch image from busybox to alpine, it worked as expected. I think k8s should update their docs with alpine example, or change the command.

Comment: Sorry, but my response little bit misleading. It's actually `nslookup` works incorrectly inside busybox, cause it returns wrong exit code. Usually people have issues inside busybox cause `ash` have different behavior, but not in your case.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the heads up. Actually I was testing the commands, and yes it was running into the first loop, and it was not going in second one, probably for the reason you explained (nslookup returns 0, instead of 1). Anyways, your suggestion to use alpine fixed the problem.

Comment: It's busybox's bug, cause when nslookup can't resolve it should return exit code 1, but it returns 0 inside busybox: `nslookup test; echo $?`. And I guess older version of nslookup had correct behavior, that's why it listed in kubernetes docs.

Comment: Yeah, it will work correctly with old busybox: `kubectl run -i --tty busybox3 --image=busybox:1.23.2 --restart=Never -- sh`